# windows encrypted rdp passwords in golang

Tags: winapi, encryption, go

like http://play.golang.org/p/fD7mx2k4Yc

window rdp password  encrypted  http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/18/how-rdp-passwords-are-encrypted/

```
   package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "syscall"
        "unsafe"
    )

    const (
        CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN = 0x1
    )

    var (
        dllcrypt32  = syscall.NewLazyDLL("Crypt32.dll")
        dllkernel32 = syscall.NewLazyDLL("Kernel32.dll")

        procEncryptData = dllcrypt32.NewProc("CryptProtectData")
        procDecryptData = dllcrypt32.NewProc("CryptUnprotectData")
        procLocalFree   = dllkernel32.NewProc("LocalFree")
    )

    type DATA_BLOB struct {
        cbData uint32
        pbData *byte
    }

    func NewBlob(d []byte) *DATA_BLOB {
        if len(d) == 0 {
            return &DATA_BLOB{}
        }
        return &DATA_BLOB{
            pbData: &d[0],
            cbData: uint32(len(d)),
        }
    }

    func (b *DATA_BLOB) ToByteArray() []byte {
        d := make([]byte, b.cbData)
        copy(d, (*[1 << 30]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(b.pbData))[:])
        return d
    }

    func Encrypt(data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
        var outblob DATA_BLOB
        r, _, err := procEncryptData.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(NewBlob(data))), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&outblob)))
        if r == 0 {
            return nil, err
        }
        defer procLocalFree.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(outblob.pbData)))
        return outblob.ToByteArray(), nil
    }

    func Decrypt(data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
        var outblob DATA_BLOB
        r, _, err := procDecryptData.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(NewBlob(data))), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&outblob)))
        if r == 0 {
            return nil, err
        }
        defer procLocalFree.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(outblob.pbData)))
        return outblob.ToByteArray(), nil
    }

    func main() {
        const secret = "MYpasswd"
        enc, err := Encrypt([]byte(secret))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Encrypt failed: %v", err)
        }
        dec, err := Decrypt(enc)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Decrypt failed: %v", err)
        }
        if string(dec) != secret {
            log.Fatalf("decrypted secret \"%s\" does not match to \"%s\".", dec, secret)
        }
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%x", enc))
        fmt.Println(string(dec))
    }
```

**out:** 01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000de7c90fbe3c9854381f0a0ffe1d496f3000000000200000000001066000000010000200000000790b641e1a9d4bfe54d81966c4d7aaeabf19b63c36dff42668e3b256edbeed8000000000e8000000002000020000000d6385d3352d5a4b011e171ab25b30271e73a4ddc0b9f9bfb8ecd13f230362a0110000000da71663217c163d7ab77231282e7d8d64000000025fbcbb72efcdc711f3a74c38bddbf0b71538f0ffe27d133c0c5cd2434f88d55d924f598ac2f94758d66a448682ed841fb56ce8c9de38601dcce6bd42aa41fbb

MYpasswd

**create  tmp.rdp**

```
screen mode id:i:1
....
winposstr:s:0,1,153,64,953,664
username:s:{{username}}
domain:s:
password 51:b:01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb0100000............
disable wallpaper:i:1
disable full window drag:i:1
```

**final：**
   mstsc.exe  tmp.rdp

**But Login failed**

python  "win32crypt.CryptProtectData"  is work.

```
    pwdHash = win32crypt.CryptProtectData(u"MYpasswd", u'pws', None, None, None, 0)
    enc_password = binascii.hexlify(pwdHash)
```

Comment: How does it not work 'in .rdp file"? What are you using to open the `.rdp` file? What do you get instead?

Comment: sorry,I have provided more detailed information.look new  posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved.

```
secret = "MYpasswd"
```

string  must use   **UTF-16LE**  encode.

Comment: how to do please?

Answer (score 2):

make an addition for the not-detailed answer above. According @Fuqiang's answer, just transfer the encoding of the plain string to `UTF-16LE` before encrypting, and it finally works. So it looks like this:

```
....

func convertToUTF16LittleEndianBytes(s string) []byte {
    u := utf16.Encode([]rune(s))
    b := make([]byte, 2*len(u))
    for index, value := range u {
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(b[index*2:], value)
    }
    return b
}

func main() {
    const secret = "MYpasswd"
    s := convertToUTF16LittleEndianBytes(secret)
    enc, err := Encrypt(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Encrypt failed: %v", err)
    }
    ...
}
```

And after decrypting, you have to decode the decrypted string from `utf-16le` before you comparing or using it, don't directly transfer the `utf-16le` char to string by `string(dec)`.