# Encrypting RDP password on Mac OS

Tags: rdp

I stole this code for a project which generates and runs .RDP files:
[windows encrypted rdp passwords in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516053/windows-encrypted-rdp-passwords-in-golang)

[The project](https://github.com/danhale-git/runrdp) writes an RDP file, runs it then deletes it. This is a simple hack for running the user's default RDP client which in my case will be:
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id1295203466?mt=12

The code works by calling procedures from DLLs. This works on Windows but, since the following DLL related calls are not cross platform, it does not build on Mac OS:

```
var (
    dLLCrypt32  = syscall.NewLazyDLL("Crypt32.dll")
    dLLKernel32 = syscall.NewLazyDLL("Kernel32.dll")

    procEncryptData = dLLCrypt32.NewProc("CryptProtectData") // LazyProc for accessing procedure
    procDecryptData = dLLCrypt32.NewProc("CryptUnprotectData")
    procLocalFree   = dLLKernel32.NewProc("LocalFree")
)

func encrypt(s string) ([]byte, error) {
    data := convertToUTF16LittleEndianBytes(s)
    var outBlob DataBlob
    // Call procedure to encrypt password.
    r, _, err := procEncryptData.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(newBlob(data))), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&outBlob)))
    if r == 0 {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer procLocalFree.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(outBlob.pbData)))
    return outBlob.toByteArray(), nil
}
```

I understand RDP password encryption is tied to the user in Windows but I'm not really sure how that works on Mac OS. It is worth noting that the client I mention above does not support saving passwords to exported RDP files. I have been unable to confirm whether this is a security feature or an OS limitation.

- Can RDP passwords be properly encrypted for use in RDP files on Mac OS? If so, any examples of how this is done? (in any language)

Any other advice is welcomed. As you can see I'm not limiting myself to clean solutions in this project.

Comment: I have re-read the question multiple times but unfortunately failed to gather the statement of the problem from it. Do you want to ask how the cited code can be ported to MacOS? If yes, I'd start with [the docs on `CryptProtectData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata).

Comment: I found a duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713606/how-to-create-rdp-file-on-mac-os-that-allows-auto-login

There is a fairly comprehensive answer on adding a configuration entry to the client but consensus on generating the actual RDP file seems to be that it isn't possible. I will keep this open in case someone can confirm/deny that.

Comment: @kostix I want to create an RDP file on Mac OS which can be double clicked resulting in an authenticated RDP session i.e. not having to manually type the password. I believe this will require the password to be encrypted in the way the Microsoft RDP Client for Mac expects.

Comment: I think you have to include the the 1st sentence of your remark into your question. But then it's not clear why the question is tagged `go` as it does not present any problem _with_ programming in Go: if I understood correctly, basically you want to know how to encrypt a password stored in an RDP "connection" file—in a way a compatible client may read it—while not resorting to calling into Win32 API as this is not cross-platform. I'd say this amounts to finding out what exactly `CryptProtectData` does and then implementing that. This problem is not related to any programming language.

Comment: You might consider asking on https://security.stackexchange.com or on https://superuser.com (tagged `windows`, `security`).

Comment: @SaltyDog have you made progress on this one? I'm thinking of using Mac's action script to fill in the username/password when asked but .. not as cool as connecting without getting prompted at all